# Scroll then fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've tried every single thing on the internet i could have find and as i'm a complete noob in js and am trying to learn some more complicated css i don't know why this scroll then fixed code is not working and don't know how to get it to work. Basically i have a header wrapper which includes header_pic of 373px height and header_nav which is 50 px in height. I just want to scroll to top of the header_nav and then set it to position fixed but every single one i used didnt work for some reason and i did include google's jQuery CDN in head area in my html page and then i included my external scrip.

Here's example of my webpage in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pyr2h0c5/

```
var elementPosition = $('#header_nav').offset();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
        $('#header_nav').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
    } else {
       $('#header_nav').css('position', 'static');
    }
});
```

Thanks for the patiance :D

Comment: Oh Jesus! where is jQuery?

Comment: Hey, small hint: take a look at the console log when your page loads and when you scroll. F12 > Console. Take a look at the errors, if any. Go from there.

Comment: When my page loads there is no errors but when i start scrolling down this thing appears: http://s2.postimg.org/aahsiy9mh/errors.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understood, you linked jQuery in your code and then included your script. You put the script in the `<head>` which makes your selected elements undefined at the time when the script runs, as they are rendered AFTER the script (like the `#header_nav` for example).

Error that's possibly thrown on scroll:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

**Solution:**
Leave jQuery where it is but take your script out of `<head>` and put it right before the closing `</body>` tag. All should be peachy:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Your HTML -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var elementPosition = $('#header_nav').offset();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
            $('#header_nav').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
        } else {
            $('#header_nav').css('position', 'static');
        }
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Too bad i can't give you the vote up because everything runs perfectly now, thank you very much. Guess i have to start from the beginning in learning javascript and jquery :)

Comment: I'll vote up him then, it seems he got the point, and @lesssugar, nice work at see the pic, its a little small.

Comment: @fuyushimoya I did not see the pic. I recreated the code at my PC and checked it.

Comment: Then I got to say i didn't notice where he included his own script from his question :P, anyway, good works!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include jquery in your jsfiddle, included it, and works...

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pyr2h0c5/2/)

No code changes...

```
var elementPosition = $('#header_nav').offset();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
        $('#header_nav').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
    } else {
        $('#header_nav').css('position', 'static');
    }
});
```

Add something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your real page's `<head>`, or try to download jQuery to local and include it locally.

Comment: He did add the jQuery in his `head` already ;) The fiddle is not the problem, the page is.

Comment: He's code just work fine, if include jquery to his jsfiddle. I just added it, and the update version works, so its probably how he include jquery has some issue.

Comment: That's what I mean. OP forgot to include jQuery *in the fiddle*, but did not forget to link jQuery in his real page.

Comment: @lesssugar No he didn include! it works if jQuery is included!

Comment: Ehhh... *and i did include google's jQuery CDN in head area in my html page and then i included my external script*

Comment: @lesssugar However, if the jsfiddle one can be solved by include jQuery, then OP's question is not reproduceable. At such situation, unless we can see what OP's real page's code, we can't give further helps.

Comment: this is my real page's html code, i included the jQuery right i think:

http://s17.postimg.org/mkmjcfv27/html.png

Comment: my whole css file is included into jsfiddle i provided